# invalid request with paypal parallel payment and php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i followed a tutorial on youtube on using parallel payments with php.
the problem is I keep getting an invalid requset error
this is an excerpt of my code:

```
$createtePacket = array(
        "actionType" => "PAY",
        "currencyCode" => "USD",
        "receiverList" => array(
            "receiver" => array(
            array("amount"=>"1.00" ,"email" => "mail@mail.com"),
            array("amount"=>"50.00" ,"email" => "mail2@mail.com"),

    )
    ),
        "returnUrl"=>"http://local.dev/store",
        "cancelUrl"=>"http://local.dev/store" ,
    "requestEnvelope" => array("errorLanguage"=>"en_US","detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll")

    );
```

and the error part of the result is :

```
 message":"Invalid request: {0}
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did. I had a misspelled header. Changed it and now it works perfect. It took me  2  and half workdays to figure it out